# BFG: mapping from old (pre-cleaning) to new hashes

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

We use git hashes to point to specific revisions, e.g., in an issue tracking system.  When cleaning a repo with BFG, all/many hashes change, so that information is lost.

Can BFG, as part of cleaning a repo, produce a mapping between old and new revision hashes?

Comment: What issue tracking system are you using?

Comment: Jira. But I mentioned that only to give an example. We use hashes as text in many places / systems.

Comment: Even if BFG could produce such a map, Jira (or another issue tracking system) would need to be smart enough to consume it.  +1 for interesting question.

Comment: Oh, I'm not dreaming of any automatism here. Being able to manually looking things up suffices for the moment. Still much better than "never find your commit again"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, and it does, by default :)

Every commit has added footer in commit message `Former-commit-id: <sha1>`. There is also file mapping old hashes to new ones generated during cleaning. You can pass runtime parameter `-private` to avoid generating this footer.

Comment: Indeed, it does. The file object-id-map.old-new.txt is what I was looking for. By now, BFG seems flawless. But the docu needs a little bit coming-to-existence.

Comment: Yup, documentation needs some improvements - I will soon send my patch to bfg, so maybe author of bfg will be willing to accept patches to documentation in future as well... I was initially skeptical of this tool, but performance-wise it trumps other options. One good manual page would make it so much easier...